# Share Cookies between certain sub-domains

Tags: asp.net, session, web, cookies, session-cookies

I have looked around StackOverflow and already found ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135734/its-possible-to-share-a-cookie-between-some-subdomains), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718933/how-to-share-cookie-on-2-sub-domains), [4](https://serverfault.com/questions/153409/can-subdomain-example-com-set-a-cookie-that-can-be-read-by-example-com))some useful info but not the exact use case that I'm trying to solve.

I'm trying to share information through server cookies for three or four different apps that share a domain but the sub-domains are a bit unusual. Moreover, I'd like to separate the cookies for the *development/staging* environment from the *live/production* environments so that cookies created by the Live environment are not readable when visiting the staging ones.

So, this is how my domains look like:

```
application 1) staging: "stgApp1.MyCompany.com", Live: "app1.MyCompany.com"

application 2) staging: "stgCase.App1.MyCompany.com", Live: "case.App1.MyCompany.com"
//Please note that application 2 is a certain use-case of application 1

application 2) staging: "stgApp3.MyCompany.com", Live: "app3.MyCompany.com"
```

Can I add these domains to each cookie individually?

Let's say something like this:

```
mycookie.domain="stgApp1.MyCompany.com,stgCase.App1.MyCompany.com,stgApp3.MyCompany.com"
```

or should I create three individual cookies for the staging environment and three for the live environments?

P.S. If it helps I'm writing the code in C#.

Comment: Are these client cookies or server cookies?

Comment: I'm saving these from the Server side